# Adaptive grid layout with expanding div

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid

I am looking for an adaptive grid type layout that will arrange grid boxes when a div is expanded. I don't want it to leave blank spaces in the grid. I have code and a graphic below to try to illustrate this.

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41b605px/1/) gives a good example of what I am trying to stop it from doing. If you click on 'a' it looks alright. If you click on 'b' or 'c' it will produce blank cell areas.

Simple code below:

```
$('.list-item').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {

        $(this).removeClass('open');

        if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
            $(this).animate({
                height: 10
            }, 0);
        } else {

            $(this).animate({
                height: 150
            }, 0);
            $(this).animate({
                width: 250
            }, 0);
        }

    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');

        if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
            $(this).animate({
                height: 330
            }, 0);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                height: 340
            }, 0);
            $(this).animate({
                width: 520
            }, 0);
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();

});

$('.list-view').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $('.list-item').removeClass('list');
        $('.list-item').animate({
            height: 150
        }, 0);
        $('.list-item').animate({
            width: 250
        }, 0);


    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $('.list-item').addClass('list');
        $('.list-item').animate({
            height: 10
        }, 0);

        $('.list-item').animate({
            width: 960
        }, 0);

    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My code in the fiddle isn't the cleanest. Another component I am missing in this is that I want only one div to be expandable at a time. If one div is expanded and a user clicks another div I want the expanded div to shrink.

[image: expanding div grid]

Thanks for your thoughts and help.